# Firebase deploy - An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: node.js, firebase, azure-devops, google-cloud-functions, azure-pipelines

I have a few firebase functions working fine locally and am able to deploy to firebase using the `firebase deploy --only functions` command fine. however, when I put the same in the Azure devops Pipeline, it's failing without giving me much information to debug. Please see my pipeline YAML below

```
trigger:
- staging
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
- name: buildToken
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}: 
    value: 'prod'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'staging') }}: 
    value: 'test'
- name: envFile
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}: 
    value: '.env.prod'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'staging') }}: 
    value: '.env.test' 

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g firebase-tools
  displayName: 'Install firebase tools'

- script: |
    npm install env-cmd --save
  displayName: 'Install env-cmd'
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: '$(envFile)'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: '$(envFile)'
    TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/functions'

- script: |
    cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/functions
    npm install -g firebase-tools
    firebase deploy --token $(FIREBASE_TOKEN) --project $(buildToken) --only functions --force
  displayName: 'Deploy to firebase $(buildToken)'
```

And I am getting below error while running the pipeline. But the output is not enough for me to troubleshoot. Any help would be really appreciated. there should be some hint saying what's going wrong.

output in the pipeline

```
Starting: Deploy to firebase prod
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.201.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/e1edf3b4-c7fd-49b6-8cac-a5fa48976989.sh
/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/12.22.12/x64/bin/firebase -> /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/12.22.12/x64/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ firebase-tools@10.9.2
updated 1 package in 4.728s

=== Deploying to 'geofleetprod'...

i  deploying functions
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env, .env.prod.

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
Finishing: Deploy to firebase prod
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Often for me, I can find "deploy failure" logs in the firebase console, under `Functions > Logs`. Have you tried looking there?